# Import error: no module named xxxxxx but there is a module named xxxxxxx

Tags: python, importerror

This is in python
I'm trying to import a folder that has important code in it. The folder is a subfolder of folder data. The subfolder is called states. I do

```
from data import states
```

But python can't find this folder. The folder does have an__init__.py and when I try and do

```
sys.path.insert
```

It says that it is a relative import with no parent package.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `from .data import states`?

Comment: Where is your python file that you're actually running in relation to this folder?

Comment: You may run the script as a module with a `-m` argument.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher this gave me the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.data'; '__main__' is not a package.

Comment: @ShiXiuFeng Ran but didn't change anything.

Comment: I figured it out! Thanks for the suggestions, I fixed it by moving states out of data and into the same directory as data, and that worked somehow.